# Why Doesn't Outlook 2013 Show the Cellspacing?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013, cellspacing

I've tried everything I can think of, but I cannot get the whitespace between cells to show in Outlook 2013. This is being sent from NationBuilder. How do I add cellspacing so that it renders in Outlook?

Thank you!

```css
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- So that mobile webkit will display zoomed in --> <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <!-- disable auto telephone linking in iOS --> <title>NationBuilder</title> <style type="text/css"> body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', serif;
}
body {
  color: #333333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
A:link {
  color: #2594aa;
  text-decoration: none
}
A:visited {
  color: #2594aa;
  text-decoration: none
}
A:active {
  color: #2594aa;
  text-decoration: none
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#bodytable {
  border-spacing: 10;
  border-collapse: sepatate;
}
#bodytable td {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
p {
  font-family: chaparral-pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.body-content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
  font-family: font-family: chaparral-pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #e37c00;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #c8d300;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize
}
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: underline
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
/* Constrain email width for small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table[class="container"] {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
/* Give content more room on mobile */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table[class="container"] {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
  div[class="body-content"]img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Styles for forcing columns to rows */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* force container columns to (horizontal) blocks */
  table[class="container"] {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
</style> </head> <body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"> <!-- 100% wrapper --> <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff"> <tr> <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"> <!-- header --> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#2594aa;"> <tr> <td align="center"> <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" border="0"> <tr> <td width="600" style="padding:20px; font-family:chaparral-pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" valign="middle" height="100"> <a href="{{ settings.site.full_url }}"><img src="{{ settings.site.meta_image_url }}" alt="{{ settings.official_name }}" width="120" height="auto" border="0" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;"></a> <a style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;padding:20px;font-size:28px;" href="{{ settings.site.full_url }}"> {
  {
    settings.official_name
  }
}
</a> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <!-- ### 600PX CONTAINER ### --> <table style="font-size: 14px;" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" border="0"> <tr> <td height="30"></td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family:'proxima-nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans;padding: 20px;line-height:1.5;background-color:#ffffff;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-ms-border-radius:5px;-o-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="body-content"> {
  {
    body
  }
}
</td> </tr> <tr> <td height="30"></td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family:'proxima-nova','Helvetica',Arial,sans;padding:20px;line-height:1.5;background-color:#ffffff;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-ms-border-radius:5px;-o-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;"> {
  {
    settings.official_name
  }
}
{
  % if settings.has_address? %
}
&middot;
 {
  {
    settings.address.one_line
  }
}
{
  % endif %
}
<br/>This email was sent to <a style="color:#505054;" href="{{ recipient.email }}"> {
  {
    recipient.email
  }
}
</a>. To stop receiving emails,
<a style="color:#505054;" href="{{ settings.site.unsubscribe_url }}">click here</a>. <a href="http://facebook.com/rogersparkfood/"> <br/><b>Don't forget to like us on Facebook!</b></a>
 <br/>You can also keep up with {
  {
    broadcaster.name
  }
}
on <a href="{{ broadcaster.twitter_profile_url }}">Twitter</a>,
<a href="{{ broadcaster.facebook_page_profile_url }}">Facebook</a> or <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rogersparkfoodcoop/">Instagram</a>. </td> </tr> </table> <p style="text-align:center;margin: 20px 40px; font-size: 0.8em;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Created with <a href="http://nationbuilder.com" style="color:#505054">NationBuilder</a>,
software for leaders.</p> <!-- ### 600PX CONTAINER ### --> </td> </tr> </table> <!--/100% wrapper--> </body> </html>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>{{ recipient.first_name_or_friend }} --
  <h1 style="color: #e37c00; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">The
  Rogers Park Food Co-op has some exciting upcoming events!</h1>
  <table id="bodytable" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="20" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 10px !important; border-collapse: separate !important; background-color:#ffffff;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f8febf; border-collapse:seperate !important;">
          <h2 style="text-decoration: none; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: #2594aa;">
          <a href="http://www.rogersparkfoodcoop.com/sustainability_open_house">Berger Park Sustainability Open House</a>
        </h2>
          <p>
            <strong>Date: April 22, 2016 from 7 - 8:30pm</strong>
            <br />
            <strong>Location: 
           Berger Park Cultural Center
          <br />
           6205 N Sheridan Rd</strong>
          </p>
          <p>
            Come celebrate the renovation of Berger Park,s south lawn! The architects plan will be unveiled. Also, Edgewater organizations committed to sustainability will have presentation tables. Share your ideas for other improvements to your park.
          </p>
          <a href="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/177/attachments/original/1460228200/April_22BergerPark2016-SustainOpenHouse.pdf?1460228200">
            <img align="right" style="margin: 6px 1px; border: 1px solid black; float: right;" title="BergerSmall.gif" src="BergerSmall.gif" alt="BergerSmall.gif" width="100" height="129" />
          </a>
          <p>Presentation Tables:</p>Berger Park South Lawn Renovation
          <br />Loyola Sustainability Institute Student sustainability projects
          <br />Edgewater Environmental Sustainability Project
          <br />Monarch butterfly project at Berger Park
          <br />LetsGOChicago
          <br />Rogers Park Food Co-op
          <br />Free Little Libraries
          <p>Please RSVP at
            <a href="https://nextdoor.com/events/il/chicago/earth-month-at-berger-park-sustainability-open-house-581265">https://nextdoor.com/events/il/chicago/earth-month-at-berger-park-sustainability-open-house-581265</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f8febf;">
          <h2 style="text-decoration: none; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: #2594aa;">

            <a href="http://www.rogersparkfoodcoop.com/meet_the_farmers">Meet the Farmers</a>
          </h2>
          <p>
            <strong>Date: 
             April 27, 2016 at 5pm - 7pm</strong>
            <br />
            <strong>Location: 
             Uncommon Ground
            <br />
             1401 W Devon Ave</strong>
          </p>
          <a href="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/174/attachments/original/1458565305/Meet_the_Farmers.jpg?1458565305">
            <img align="right" style="float: right; margin: 6px 1px; border: 1px solid black;" title="MeettheFarmers_sm.jpg" src="MeettheFarmers_sm.jpg" alt="MeettheFarmers_sm.jpg" width="100" height="155" />
          </a>
          <p>FREE EVENT!</p>
          <p>Get some face-time with the local farmers who supply the best Chicago restaurants and Farmers Markets!</p>
          <p>Learn about where your food comes from by talking to the people who grow it!</p>
          <p>Get 10% off Dinner from Uncommon Ground!</p>
          <p>Stay for live musicfrom 8-10 pm.</p>
          <p>RSVP
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/187709778277126/">here</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f8febf;">
          <h2 style="text-decoration: none; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: #2594aa;">

            <a href="http://www.rogersparkfoodcoop.com/farm_fresh_jams">Farm Fresh Jams</a>
          </h2>
          <p>
            <strong>Date: 
             April 27, 2016 at 8pm - 10pm</strong>
            <br />
            <strong>Location: 
             Uncommon Ground
            <br />
             1401 W Devon Ave</strong>
          </p>
          <a href="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/173/attachments/original/1458531431/PosterDraft.PNG?1458531431">
            <img align="right" style="float: right; margin: 6px 1px; border: 1px solid black;" title="FarmFresh_sm.jpg" src="FarmFresh_sm.jpg" alt="FarmFresh_sm.jpg" width="100" />
          </a>
          <p>Fundraiser Concert for the Rogers Park Food Co-op</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Featuring performances by:</strong>
          </p>
          <p>Signal-to-Noise</p>
          <p>Luna Blu</p>
          <p>Abbie &amp; Marlon</p>
          <p>Abud: A Bard.</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Get 10% off Dinner from Uncommon Ground!</strong>
          </p>
          <p></p>
          <p>RSVP
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/495150530668190/">here</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f8febf;">
          <h2 style="text-decoration: none; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: #2594aa;">

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/211139905915958/">Moah&#39;s Ark 4th Annual Plant Sale</a>
          </h2>
          <p>
            <strong>Date:May 7th and 8th</strong>
            <br />
            <strong>Location:Moah&#39;s ark</strong>
            <br />
            <strong>1839 W Touhy Ave</strong>
          </p>
          <a href="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/173/attachments/original/1458531431/PosterDraft.PNG?1458531431">
            <img align="right" style="float: right; margin: 6px 1px; border: 1px solid black;" title="moah.jpg" src="moah.jpg" alt="moah.jpg" width="250" height="188" />
          </a>
          <p>Our 4th annual plant sale will feature a big variety of heirloom tomatoes and peppers, plus herbs, flowers and more.
          </p>
          <p>We have several new tomatoes, including 7 varieties of dwarf heirlooms, old favorites like the cherokee purple, green and chocolate, Moah&#39;s yellow, and a couple new italian imports.</p>
          <p>This is a 2 day event, Saturday and Sunday, which is Mother&#39;s Day. Mom&#39;s get a free plant.</p>
          <p>RSVP to this event so that you will be notified of the full list which i will be putting up soon.</p>
          <p>Happy spring!!</p>
          <p>RSVP
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/211139905915958/">here</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2 style="color: #e37c00; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">

            <a href="http://www.rogersparkfoodcoop.com/events">Click Here For Full Event Listing</a>
          </h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f8febf;">
          <h2 style="text-decoration: none; font-family: &#39;Trebuchet MS&#39;, sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize; color: #2594aa;">
        Exclusive Offers for Co-op Owners!</h2>
          <p>In our effort to provide value for our Owners, the Rogers Park Food Co-op is excited to offer the following exclusive deals for owners!</p>
          <h3>$50 Discount to Natures Farm Camp</h3>
          <p>To celebrate their love of Co-ops, Nature&#39;s Farm Camps has decided to offer a $50.00 discount for Natures Farm Camp registrations to the Chicago-area food cooperative members.</p>
          <p>
            <em>
            <strong>Owners will receive a coupon code in an upcoming email.</strong>
          </em>
          </p>
          <p>From naturesfarmcamp.com:</p>
          <blockquote>We are an overnight summer camp where kids (ages 8-14) step out of their every day and immerse themselves in nature growing, foraging, cooking, making, building and exploring. Campers do with their hands, head and heart. In the process they
            discover more about life and themselves, all while having a blast with new friends in the great outdoors.
          </blockquote>
          <hr />
          <h3>Biggest Slim-Down with Hank: Help The Co-op While Getting Fit!</h3>
          <p>Every few months, personal trainer Hank Rouse and his team of coaches run a Biggest Slim Down Contest. This past Holiday Season we had a Maintain Don&#39;t Gain Contest. To win cash prizes, all the contestants had to do was maintain their weight
            (or even lose weight). I&#39;m so excited to announce an Exclusive Opportunity for RPFC Co-Owners.</p>$25 will be donated to the Rogers Park Food Co-op for each participating Co-Owner who achieves the 3% Body Weight (Loss/Gain) benchmark.
          <p>NEW Contest: Begins April 18th</p>
          <p>Applications accepted until April 13th.</p>More Information at
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/events/495659513953786/">http://www.facebook.com/events/495659513953786/</a> 

          <br />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>{{ broadcaster.name }}
  <br />
  <a href="{{%20settings.site.full_url%20}}">{{ settings.site.full_url }}</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/63v8cra7/1/

Screenshot from Thunderbird:
[image]

From Outlook:
[image]